# ckeditor remove specific attributes from a tab

Tags: configuration, ckeditor, widget

In the the ckeditor init, to remove dialog tabs, it is possible to do something like:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
   {
      // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
      var dialogName = ev.data.name;
      var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

      // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're interested in
      if ( dialogName == 'link' )
      {
        dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'advanced' );
      }
   });
```

This will remove the "advanced" tab from the link dialog.

It also possible to remove specific attributes from a tab, doing something like:

```
     var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

     // Remove unnecessary widgets from the 'Link Info' tab.         
     infoTab.remove( 'linkType');
     infoTab.remove( 'protocol');
```

So this works fine, but my problem is I could not find a detailed list of the attributes names, like 'linkType' or 'protocol' in the example above.

Basically I would like to remove, from the image dialog for example, the width, height, the css class and id from the advanced tab etc, but I cannot find a the names of these attributes in the ckeditor documentation, does someone know where I can find this ?
Or give a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Developer tools plugin as explained in the HowTos: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Field_Names